# Angular and ChartJS colors

Tags: javascript, angularjs, chart.js

I am using Angular chart js. does anyone know how to switch the chart colors every other row.

here is my markup:

```
<canvas ng-if="hasStats" id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
chart-type="Pie" 
chart-colours=colors 
chart-data="data" 
chart-labels="labels" 
chart-legend="true">
</canvas>
```

here is my js:

```
$scope.labels = ["label 1", "label 2", "label 3"];
$scope.data = [300, 200, 500];
$scope.colors = [{
              fillColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.2)',
              strokeColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
              pointColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
              pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
              pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
              pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.8)'
            },
              {
                fillColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.8)'
              },
            {
                fillColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,0.8)'
              }];
```

The markup is in a table. I would like to switch the color scheme to match my rows. odd rows are one color scheme and even are another.

UPDATE:
it could be something like this:

```
$scope.colorsOdd = [{ // facebook blue
              fillColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.2)',
              strokeColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
              pointColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
              pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
              pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
              pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.8)'
            },
              { // twitter blue
                fillColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.8)'
              },
            { // mav
                fillColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(233, 30, 99,0.8)'
              }];

  $scope.colorsEven = [{ // facebook blue
              fillColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.2)',
              strokeColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
              pointColor: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,1)',
              pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
              pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
              pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(59, 89, 152,0.8)'
            },
              { // twitter blue
                fillColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(0, 132, 180,0.8)'
              },
            { // teal
                fillColor: 'rgba(91, 192, 222,0.2)',
                strokeColor: 'rgba(91, 192, 222,1)',
                pointColor: 'rgba(91, 192, 222,1)',
                pointStrokeColor: '#fff',
                pointHighlightFill: '#fff',
                pointHighlightStroke: 'rgba(91, 192, 222,0.8)'
              }];
```

I just can't figure out the best way to switch between them

UPDATE 2:

```
<td rowspan="5" width="200">
                    <div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="AmbasPieCtrl" ng-init="init(data)" style="width: 250px;">
                        <canvas ng-if="hasStats" id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
                        chart-type="Pie" 
                        chart-colours=colors
                        chart-data="data" 
                        chart-labels="labels" 
                        chart-legend="true">
                        </canvas> 
                        <div ng-if="!hasStats" class="text-center">
                            <h4>No stats found</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </td>
```

Comment: have you tried changing `fillColor`?

Comment: What do you mean? as seen above I use fillColor. What I would like is to have a second set of three colors and odd rows gets set 1, even rows get set 2

Comment: ah ok - i see what ur saying

Comment: I updated the post with an idea

Comment: what about using the ng-if somehow?

Comment: does that canvas tag create the entire table?

Comment: no the canvas tag is inside the table. I will update the post to show it

Comment: cool ok...but is it responsible for populating the rows?

Comment: nope this is: `<table class="table table-condensed table-outer" ng-repeat="data in filtered = (list | filter:search | orderBy : predicate :reverse) | startFrom:(currentPage-1)*entryLimit | limitTo:entryLimit">`

Comment: @ewizard, I was looking at this: `ng-class-odd="'odd'" ng-class-even="'even'"` but could not get it to work correctly with `chart-colours=color`

Comment: just trying to wrap my head around it...but it seems like you might need to introduce another table...with a separate ng-repeat for both odd and even maybe?

Comment: let me check out the docs for ng-class-odd and even i think ive seen those before

Comment: yah that actually looks like it might be the way to go

Comment: when I add it to the canvas tag i can get odd and even classes but I can not figure out how to comunicate that to this parameter: `chart-colours=colors` to call the different color schemes. i.e. `chart-colours=colorsOdd` or `chart-colours=colorsEven`

Comment: it looks like `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` just reference css classes...when you set it up did you make an `.even` and `.odd` class in your css file - then you can add your color schemes to css instead of javascript.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108861/discussion-between-jason-and-ewizard).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of @ewizard I was able to get it working properly.

here is the revised markup:

```
<div class="ng-scope" ng-controller="AmbasPieCtrl" ng-init="init(data)" style="width: 250px;">
                        <div ng-if="hasStats">
                            <div ng-hide="$odd">
                                <canvas id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
                                chart-type="Pie" 
                                chart-colours=colorsEven
                                chart-data="data" 
                                chart-labels="labels" 
                                chart-legend="true">
                                </canvas>
                            </div>
                            <div ng-hide="$even">
                                <canvas ng-if="hasStats" id="pie" class="chart chart-pie"
                                chart-type="Pie" 
                                chart-colours=colorsOdd
                                chart-data="data" 
                                chart-labels="labels" 
                                chart-legend="true">
                                </canvas>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-if="!hasStats" class="text-center">
                            <h4>No stats found</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```